# Print function Using DGVPrinter class

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, datagridview

I am using DGVPrinter class for printing my windows form data. after gridview unable to print any text

```
        DGVPrinter printer = new DGVPrinter();
        Bitmap bitmap1 = new Bitmap(@"D:\Aur.jpg");

        DGVPrinter.ImbeddedImage img1 = new DGVPrinter.ImbeddedImage();
        img1.theImage = bitmap1; img1.ImageX = 3; img1.ImageY = 3;
        img1.ImageAlignment = DGVPrinter.Alignment.Right;
        img1.ImageLocation = DGVPrinter.Location.Header;
        printer.ImbeddedImageList.Add(img1);
        printer.SubTitle = getprocess_setvalupar();
        printer.SubTitleAlignment = StringAlignment.Far;            
        printer.SubTitleFormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft;
        printer.PageNumbers = true;
        printer.PageNumberInHeader = true;
        printer.PorportionalColumns = true;
        printer.HeaderCellAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        printer.Footer = GetSignatureFooter("XXXXX Ltd");
        printer.FooterSpacing = 15;            
        printer.PrintDataGridView(dataGridView1);
```

I am unable to print some text after gridview. If i tried to call function after             printer.PrintDataGridView(dataGridView1);text not displaying

I am able to print subtitle before gridview in page. but unable after gridview.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!
 - Also: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name! - Finally: _DGVPrinter class_ Now what is that? A CodeProject project? Better clarify that!

Comment: sorry for that. i am fresher. its windows application DGVPrinter is third part clas. we can print from windows application. https://github.com/vijaythapa333/DGVPrinter

Comment: You can probably use the `Footer` property to pass a line of text to print after.

Comment: getting footer property for that text getting alignment issues if do like that. and missing datagridview rows also